# Tips for creating a liquidity pool in Pancake Swap

Tags: tokens, ico, pancakeswap, presale, liquidity

dear friends

I need the advice of my dear professional friends on this site in several areas, please advise and guide me in all areas.

The first part is, what is the best strategy for financing a project with a very limited budget?
For example, is it good to first run a Pre-ICO or Pre-sale through the project's official website in order to obtain enough funds to create liquidity in Pancake Swap, or should a small and limited amount of liquidity be created in Pancake Swap before the token pre-sale?

The second part refers to the strategy for creating liquidity, how much of the project token should be placed in the liquidity pool with what amount of the desired currency pair?

The third part is that considering that the project token is deployed and built in the Binance blockchain, is it appropriate to use Binance network stable coins such as BUSD for token liquidity currency pairs in Pancake Swap?

Finally, what strategy do you suggest for the economic parts of a project with a very limited budget?

Thank you for your help...